# having a problem while working with mysql& node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I tried to create an object with data which I get from the DB I work with.

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
//creating an obj with a class i created
  });
});
```

but I can`t return the object I created because it shows me it's undefined (it is returned to the "small" function I created in the brackets.

does someone have any idea of a solution for this problem?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where are you trying to return the result to? Why not just use it in the `query` callback?

Comment: I wrote those lines in a static method, and I tried to return the object from the method I wrote to an another.
and how?